# Python/Pandas - Remove the first row with Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 1,Unnamed: 2,Unnamed: 3,Unnamed: 4,Unnamed: 5,Unnamed: 6,Unnamed: 7

Tags: python, pandas

I am splitting a xlsm file ( with multiple sheets) into a csv with each sheet as a separate csv file. In the process I am removing first 4 lines and keeping the header only which start from row 5.
Here is the input file

[image]

This is the output I expect -

[image]

But I am getting the below output -

[image]

Here is the code I am using -

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile('Sample_File.xlsm')
for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name=sheet)
    df1 = df.iloc[3:]
    df1.to_csv(f"{sheet}.csv",index=False)
```

How can I remove the first row which is having values from unnamed: 0 to unnamed: 9?

Also how can I have comment1 show up in both (First and second row) and comment2 in (Third and Fourth row) in last column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `skiprows` argument inside the `pd.read_excel` function to correctly get the column names in the 5th row.

**UPDATE** Including the forward filling

```
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile('Sample_File.xlsm')

for sheet in xl.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name=sheet, skiprows=4) # no more iloc here
    df['Comment'] = df['Comment'].ffill()
    df.to_csv(f'{sheet}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It work liked charm. How to fix the second issue where we need to have the comment column (Last column) value in all the rows it belongs?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need to `df['Comment'] = df['Comment'].ffill()` to forward fill values before exporting.